# Chrome Dev tools won't show ajax request response

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, google-chrome

I have a nodejs application where I make some ajax request using jquery. In developer tools response of last ajax request is empty if I make redirection, otherwise response exists. Is there any logic to why wouldn't it show response in case of redirection.

I don't understand redirection is made in ajax callback and based on values from response, redirection is made properly which means response exist but chrome dev tools won't show it, What am i doing wrong?

here is my callback

```
   .done(function (response)
   {
      if (response.errorCode == "00") {
          //window.location = "/"; //no response shown if dev tools if i uncomment this
          console.log("Yeah i got some response " + response);
      }
   })
```

Comment: try permuting the `window.location` and `console.log` lines. is it the same?

Comment: @Matyas still nothing

Comment: well another thing is that when `window.location` is set, the console is cleared (because of new page load). Enable the `Preserve the log upon navigation` option

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure `Preserve the log upon navigation` is enabled in chrome dev tools settings.
   [image]
2. Let

   ```
   window.location = '/whatever/address';
   ```

   be the last thing you call, or do it later using

   ```
   setTimeout( function () { 
       window.location = '/whatever/address'; 
   }, 1);`
   ```
3. Beware that all values of variables will be lost on a new page load / navigation

Comment: Preserve in check, window.location is called after response is logged to console, still chrome dev tools dev show's request but its response is empty, while objects are properly logged into console..

Answer (score 0):

After redirection everything gets reloaded that's why you are not able to access response.
To solve this you can first use your response object & then redirect your page.